# Calculate the expectation of the product of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory

There is a sequence of independent and identically distributed continuous random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with common density function $f(x)$. We say that a record occurs at time $n$ if $X_n > \max(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n-1})$. Consider the random variable $Y_i$ defined as: $Y_i = 1$ if a record occurs at time $i$, $Y_i = 0$ otherwise. Compute $E[Y_i \cdot Y_j]$ where $i < j$.

I compute like this:
$$E[Y_i \cdot Y_j] = P(Y_i = Y_j = 1) = P(Y_i=1 \mid Y_j=1)P(Y_j=1).$$
Since $P(Y_j=1)=1/j$ and $$P(Y_i=1 \mid Y_j=1) = P(Y_i=1) = 1/i,$$ then $E[Y_i \cdot Y_j]=1/(ij)$.
It seems not quite right and I am not very sure about it. The reason why I'm not so sure about it is that, it seems by this way, the events "the record occurs at the time $i$" and "the record occurs at the time $j$" would be independent. But given "the record occurs at the time $j$", would it be harder for "the record occurs at the time $i$" to happen? Because $X_j > X_i$, and $X_i$ cannot be very big to be the record.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How did you conclude that $P(Y_i = 1 \, | \, Y_j = 1) = P(Y_i = 1)$?

Comment: If Yj = 1, then any of X1, ... Xi still have equal chance to be the biggest number, no matter Yj is 1 or not. So Yi = 1 have a probability 1/i.

Comment: The event $Y_j=1$ is more likely, if $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}$ are small and less likely, if they are big. Thus I would say, that $(Y_i = 1)$ is more likely if $(Y_j=1)$ has occurred.

Comment: You might consider trying a simulation to get some intuition for how $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ should be connected.

Comment: I personally think this problem is not that hard. I mean, by symmetry, see the reply I made above, if I didn't think wrongly. If we just consider it as a combination problem, it would be equivalent to ask, given randomly n different numbers and make a sequence, what's the probability that the ith number is greater than the first i -1 ones and the jth number is greater than the first j -1 ones.

Comment: You can consider a simpler case to see why they cannot be independent: if instead $X_n$ can only take on $k$ possible values then there can only ever be $k$ records. Once there have been $k$ records, there cannot be any more records. So there is some nontrivial combinatorics to be done here I think...

Comment: It's continuous random number here. However, as you said, in discrete case, the problem seems to be more complex.

Comment: My example is not "trapped" in the discrete world: in general when more records have already occurred, the chance of another record coming up at a given step is diminished.

Comment: Ian: I tried to do the calculations and quite surprisingly also arrived at 1/(ij). Would you mind to check it below?

Comment: In the *particular* case of the uniform (0,1) distribution, this result is not so surprising, because it has a self-similarity property: a uniform (0,1) distribution conditional on being greater than a is a uniform (a,1) distribution. In the general continuous case I don't think this works; if you tried some CDF transformation technique and deduced the same result then I am skeptical of its correctness.

Comment: I just applied the transformation $t \mapsto F(t)$ to all the inequalities, where $F$ is the continuous distribution function of $X$.

Comment: Hmm...from the sampling perspective that makes sense, because $X_1 = Q(U_1),X_2=Q(U_2)$ so that $X_1<X_2$ iff $U_1<U_2$ (here $Q$ is the quantile function). That's weird that this would be so different between the discrete and continuous cases, though.

Comment: From my experience with these problems related to extreme value theory, the continuous case is often extremely much nicer than the discrete case. But I am surprised myself. I will try to run a few samples and post my results.

Comment: Furrer's argument seems to show what's going on correctly. The idea is just to directly calculate everything in the uniform case and then note that in the general continuous case, $X_1<X_2$ is equivalent to $Q(U_1)<Q(U_2)$ which is equivalent to $U_1<U_2$. In the discrete case this is no longer true, because the quantile function is flat on some regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to express the probability as (see below)

$P(Y_i = Y_j = 1) = \int_{(0,1)^2} p(u_1,u_2) \mathrm{d}(u_1,u_2)$,

where for a iid sequence $(U_k)$, each $\text{Unif}(0,1)$-distributed,

$p(u_1,u_2)= P(u_2 \geq u_1, u_2 \geq U_{j-1}, \ldots , u_2 \geq U_{i+1}, u_1 \geq U_{i-1}, \ldots , u_1 \geq U_1)$.

This probability is due to independence,

$p(u_1,u_2) = \mathbb{1}_{u_2\geq u_1} \prod_{k=i+1}^{j-1} P(U_k\leq u_2) \prod_{k=1}^{i-1} P(U_k \leq u_1)$,

where the product as usually is $1$ if the lower index is higher than the upper index. Then the integral becomes

$P(Y_i = Y_j = 1)
=
\int_{(0,1)} u_2^{j-i-1}  \int_0^{u_2} u_1^{i-1}    \, \mathrm{d}u_1 \mathrm{d}u_2, \\
=
\int_{(0,1)} \frac{1}{i} u_2^{j-1} \, \mathrm{d}u_2
=
\frac{1}{ij},
$

in accordance with your intuition. I am actually quite surprised by this result - maybe there is an easier way to show it. But your argument of independence is in my opinion not clear enough for a formal proof. Also, the above does not imply independence.

Comment: As promised in the above answer, here an argument for my first equality:

$P(Y_i = Y_j = 1) \\
=
P(X_j > X_i, X_j > X_{j-1},\ldots,X_j > X_{i+1}, X_i > X_{i-1}, \ldots, X_i > X_1) \\
=
P(U_j \geq U_i, U_j \geq U_{j-1},\ldots,U_j \geq U_{i+1}, U_i \geq U_{i-1}, \ldots, U_i \geq U_1) \\
=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} P(U_j \geq U_i, U_j \geq U_{j-1},\ldots,U_j \geq U_{i+1}, U_i \geq U_{i-1}, \ldots, U_i \geq U_1 | U_i = u_1, U_j = u_2) \, \mathrm{d}(U_i,U_j)(P)(u_1,u_2) \\
=
\int_{(0,1)^2} p(u_1,u_2) \, \mathrm{d}(u_1,u_2)$.

Comment: For the second equality I use the classical trick of transforming the problem to one of uniform random variables, see also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922950/x-y-and-z-are-continuous-iid-textpxyz/1924477#1924477

Comment: I am sorry that I need more effort to digest what you have written. Still thank you for help! I am always intimidated by using calculus to do probability problems :(

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry. I try not to use calculus unecessarily - but here I couldn't find another approach. Take a look and be free to ask any question, that turns up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run some simulations to figure out, what was going on. The interested reader could try to run the following R-code, where I have considered some different scenarios.

```
rm(list = ls())

set.seed(2)

### Uniform case ###

n <- 20
m <- 10000

U <- matrix(runif(n*m), nrow = m, ncol = n)

Y <- matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)

for(k in 1:m){
  Y[k, ] <- c(1, (U[k, 2:n]>cummax(U[k, 1:(n-1)])))
}

#Some comparisons:
mean(Y[ ,5]*Y[ ,7]) ; 1/(5*7)
mean(Y[ ,2]*Y[ ,13]); 1/(2*13)
mean(Y[ ,3]*Y[ ,4]) ; 1/(3*4)
mean(Y[ ,16]*Y[ ,18]) ; 1/(16*18)

### Non-uniform case ###

n <- 20
m <- 10000

E <- matrix(rexp(n*m, 2), nrow = m, ncol = n)

Y <- matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)

for(k in 1:m){
  Y[k, ] <- c(1, (E[k, 2:n]>cummax(E[k, 1:(n-1)])))
}

#Some comparisons:
mean(Y[ ,5]*Y[ ,7]) ; 1/(5*7)
mean(Y[ ,2]*Y[ ,13]); 1/(2*13)
mean(Y[ ,3]*Y[ ,4]) ; 1/(3*4)
mean(Y[ ,16]*Y[ ,18]) ; 1/(16*18)

### Discrete case ###

n <- 20
m <- 100000

D <- matrix(rbinom(n*m, 50, 1/2), nrow = m, ncol = n)

Y <- matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)

for(k in 1:m){
  Y[k, ] <- c(1, (D[k, 2:n]>cummax(D[k, 1:(n-1)])))
}

#Some comparisons:
mean(Y[ ,5]*Y[ ,7]) ; 1/(5*7)
mean(Y[ ,2]*Y[ ,13]); 1/(2*13)
mean(Y[ ,3]*Y[ ,4]) ; 1/(3*4)
mean(Y[ ,16]*Y[ ,18]) ; 1/(16*18)
```